# unity broken after update

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, ubuntu-unity

Ubuntu 12.04

After applying updates today I've lost unity3d.

apt-get gives the following message:

unity : Depends: unity-common (= 5.12+bzr2444ubuntu0+709) but 5.12+bzr2445ubuntu0+709 is to be installed

Any ideas on how to either downgrade or solve this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.

Download the unity package here:
http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/staging/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity/unity_5.12+bzr2444ubuntu0+709_amd64.deb

and install it manually with: sudo dpkg -i --force-all unity_5.12+bzr2444ubuntu0+709_amd64.deb

make sure unity-common is installed first.

Comment: Thanks, I already fixed it.  Actually, the kernel was updated but the nvidia driver was not so when I reinstalled the nvidia driver I was then able to reinstall unity etc.